# Special characters >: and <: meaning in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I use scala 2.10:

does any know what is the meanning of:

type Session >: Null <: SessionDef

I do not understand character >: and <: in here

the whole code is:

```
trait DatabaseComponent { self =>

type Session >: Null <: SessionDef

}
```

Comment: Search for "type bounds" in the [Scala Language Specification (SLS)](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) and elsewhere, e.g. http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/136 , http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/lower-type-bounds.html , https://gist.github.com/retronym/257758

Comment: Can you tell me why type bound used here, I mean I think the "type" mean defined new type name. if here the Session is the upper type bounds of Null is so clear, I do not think it need to redefine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `type` keyword defines some abstract type. A specific `DatabaseComponent` subclass (a concrete implementation) can implement this type as a concrete class.

The `>:` and `<:` are type bounds on the abstract type `Session`. The ones in the example mean that an abstract type member `Session` is `null`-able and it is a subtype of some other type `SessionDef`.

The upper bound `SessionDef` (`<:`) is here because:

- an implementation of `DatabaseComponent` can only define `Session` types such that they are subtypes of `SessionDef`
- if some method in `DatabaseComponent` happens to return an object of type `Session`, you won't know its exact implementation, but you will know that you can call whatever method exists in `SessionDef` on it

The lower bound `Null` (`>:`) is here because it allows you to initialize variables of type `Session` with a `null` value.

Read more about [abstract type members here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/abstract-types.html) and [type bounds here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/lower-type-bounds.html).